# xslt variable with a list of elements

Tags: xslt

I have xslt code as follows. Fill does not select any color. How to fix this code:
fill="{($series_color)/color[$index+1]}"

```
<xsl:variable name="series_color">
    <color>#99FF99</color>
    <color>#0099FF</color>
    <color>#FF6600</color>
    <color>#990099</color>
    <color>#FF99FF</color>
    <color>#666600</color>
    <color>#CC99F0</color>
    <color>#CC990F</color>
    <color>#CC09FF</color>
    <color>#0C99FF</color>
    <color>#C599FF</color>
    <color>#CC59FF</color>
    <color>#CC95FF</color>
    <color>#CC995F</color>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="legend">
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="100 div count(./series)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="./series">
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="count(preceding::series)"/>
        <rect x="{$index * $width}%" y="0" width="{$width}%" height="100%" fill="{($series_color)/color[$index+1]}" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: if this is XSLT 1.0, `$series_color` is a *result tree fragment* and not a *node-set*. Google *exsl:node-set*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guess: since you are generating a `<rect>` element, and SVG has a `<rect>` element, I guess you are generating SVG, which means your stylesheet probably uses the SVG namespace as the default namespace. If that's correct, the elements in $series_color are in the SVG namespace too, and need to be addressed as svg:color.

This illustrates the importance of providing a complete runnable example. When the bug is in code that you've trimmed out (in this case the xsl:stylesheet header) it makes it very difficult to find it.

Comment: I wrote a test program to test "exslt:node-set", but it does not work. Firefox report error: "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed." The code as follows:  <xsl:variable name="series_color">
 <color>#99FF99</color>
 <color>#0099FF</color>
 <color>#FF6600</color>
 <color>#990099</color>
 <color>#FF99FF</color>
 <color>#666600</color>
</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="1"/>
    colorx: <xsl:value-of select="exslt:node-set($series_color/color[$index+1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: I found how to get right color vaiable under xls. <xsl:variable name="colorN" select="exslt:node-set($series_color)/color[$index+1]"/>. But it seems svg rect command does not take fill="{$colorN}". How to input vaiable colorN to rect under svg?

Comment: I told you it's difficult to help without complete code. Why do you ignore that advice?